# Replacing an Carrierwave Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

Using Carrierwave (0.10.0), I'm trying to replace an existing image for one of my records by setting the `image` attribute to a new image. However, when I do this, the new image is not saved and the `image` attribute is set as an empty string.

```
post = Post.last
post.image? # => true
post.image # => /uploads/post/1/a.png
post.image = File.new(Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images", "b.png"))
post.save # => true
post.image? # => false
post.image.inspect # => ""
```

I've tried calling `remove_image!` and `remove_previously_stored_image` beforehand, with the same result. Am I overwriting this image incorrectly or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe use `File.open` instead of `new`

Comment: I've tried `File.open`, same result :( .